# Bind a HiddenField within a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hidden-field

I want to bind a `Hidden Field` because I want to pass a value from code behind to the `asp:Parameter Name="HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID" Type="Int32"`.

My asp:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdating" >
    <EditItemTemplate>           
        HOME_TEAM:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListHometeam" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataGetTeams"
            DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("HOME_TEAM_ID") %>'>
        </asp:DropDownList>  
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="testLabel" Value='<%# Bind("HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID") %>' /> 
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

And c# behind is:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        DropDownList HomeTeamId = FormView1.FindControl("DropDownListHometeam") as DropDownList;            
        string team = string.Format("{0}", HomeTeamId.Text);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BasketballConnectionString1"].ToString());
        conn.Open();
        string queryHome = "SELECT dbo.COACH.ID, dbo.COACH.SURENAME FROM dbo.COACH INNER JOIN dbo.GAMES ON dbo.COACH.TEAM_ID = dbo.GAMES.HOME_TEAM_ID WHERE (dbo.GAMES.HOME_TEAM_ID =" + team + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryHome, conn); 


        var Home_Coach_Id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        HiddenField HomeCoachIdLabel = FormView1.FindControl("testLabel") as HiddenField;
        HomeCoachIdLabel.Value = Convert.ToString(Home_Coach_Id);
        conn.Close();
```

I want Help with the last four lines where I want to pass the `Home_Coach_Id` value to bind the `asp:HiddenField ID="testLabel" Value='<%# Bind("HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID") %>'`.

When I click update, it doesn't change the value in database. (When I debug, in the last lines it gives me the correct `HomeCoachIdLabel.Value`.)
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it needs the method prerender and not the method onitemupdated.

```
   asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" OnPreRender="FormView1_OnPreRender" >
```

and also in c#

```
    protected void FormView1_OnPreRender(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
```

{

It also works when I put it in page load{ }.
The next step is to make the insert event....

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the explicitly set the `HiddenField`'s `Value` property, because it is done by the `<%# Bind("HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID") %>` in your markup.

I believe your problem is that you are not returning the `HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID` from your query to the database in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT dbo.COACH.ID, dbo.COACH.SURENAME FROM dbo.COACH 
    INNER JOIN dbo.GAMES ON dbo.COACH.TEAM_ID = dbo.GAMES.HOME_TEAM_ID 
    WHERE (dbo.GAMES.HOME_TEAM_ID =" + team + ")
```

Comment: When I debug the query, it returns an int value (Id).I need to pass this value to HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID column in database.

Comment: @Apollon - so you need to do an `UPDATE` not a `SELECT` and use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `.ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: When I update it executes from the asp sqldatasource this query: UpdateCommand="UPDATE GAMES SET AGONISTIKI = AGONISTIKI, HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID = @HOME_TEAM_COACH_ID WHERE (ID = @ID)"